# Qt 6 Android: Gradle failure to build with built-in JAR error

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qt6, qtandroidextras

I'm attempting to build for Android with Qt 6 and Qt Creator.

When attempting to build any project, Widgets or Quick, for Android, including example projects, the following build errors occur.

```
ERROR:/hdd/code/build-AndroidWidgets-Android_Qt_6_6_1_aarch64_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/libs/Qt6AndroidNetworkInformationBackend.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:/hdd/code/build-AndroidWidgets-Android_Qt_6_6_1_aarch64_Clang_arm64_v8a-Debug/android-build/libs/Qt6Android.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Running SDK 12, NDK 25, Java 17 (11 doesn't work), Android 14, Qt 6.6.1. Projects use CMake but Creator internally calls Gradle where this error occurs.

I searched the Qt forums to no avail. I feel like this may be a system issue...

I tried completely reinstalling the Android SDK, Qt 6, Qt Creator, etc. I don't have any other systems available for testing right now but will soon so I will see if they fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the AUR packages for the Android aarch64 Qt 6 library are broken. Using the online installer fixes this.